How can I add an optional closure to a ViewModifier?
Playing around with SwiftUI I'm struggling to grasp closures. I have a web view to which I add a toolbar (a ViewModifier) using a View extension. Now I want to expand the toolbar with an optional button. If the web view has a history, I want to show a button in the toolbar to allow a user to go back. This is what I have.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            WebView()
                .addToolbar()
        }
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: URL
    var webView: WKWebView

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        webView = WKWebView()
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }

    func goBack() {
        webView.goBack()
    }

    func canGoBack() -> Bool {
        webView.canGoBack
    }
}

struct Toolbar: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func addToolbar() -> some View {
        self.modifier(Toolbar())
    }
}

I want to change the code in such a way that I write the ContentView something like this.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            WebView()
                .addToolbar({ view in
                    if view.canGoBack() {
                        Button {
                            view.goBack()
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                        }
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}

I've tried changing the extension and Toolbar to something like this, but I get errors in the Toolbar most often because I need an input that I don't have access to.
struct Toolbar: ViewModifier {
    var backNavigation: ((WebView) -> Void)?

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    HStack {
                        // I need a WebView input parameter here but I don't have any?
                        // I'd thought I could cast content to WebView or get the WebView being modified from the content input, but that doesn't seem to be the case.
                        backNavigation?()

                        Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func addToolbar(backNavigation: ((WebView -> Void)? = nil) -> some View {
        self.modifier(Toolbar(backNavigation: backNavigation))
    }
}

To try and get a better feel for it I've tried declaring the button in the Toolbar instead of in the closure in the ContentView, but I can't seem to get a firm grasp on how this works/should work.
How can I call/execute the backNavigation closure in the Toolbar ViewModifier? How can I get the WebView that is being modified by the addToolbar() view extension so I can pass that as input to the backNavigation closure call in the Toolbar?

Try thinking of the problem in a declerative way

The UIViewRepresentable needs to expose canGoBack to the SwiftUI world. This can be done with a Binding like how Picker exposes its selection through a binding.
It also needs to provide a way for SwiftUI code to trigger goBack(). This is usually done via a "trigger" parameter. When the value passed to that parameter changes, something is triggered. This is similar to how PhaseAnimator takes a trigger parameter.
Here I have grouped all these things into a single struct called WebViewState (I have also added properties for going forward to make the pattern more obvious).
struct WebViewState {
    var canGoBack = false
    var canGoForward = false
    fileprivate var goBackTrigger = false
    fileprivate var goForwardTrigger = false
    
    mutating func goBack() {
        goBackTrigger.toggle()
    }
    
    mutating func goForward() {
        goForwardTrigger.toggle()
    }
}

The UIViewRepresentable can take a @Binding of WebViewState. It should observe changes in the WKWebView's canGoBack and canGoForward and set the WebViewState's corresponding properties. Here I have used a Combine publisher with KVO, but of course this is not the only way to observe changes.
Then in updateUIView, it should see if any of the triggers have changed. If they did change, call the appropriate WKWebView method. Here I have simply used the Coordinator to store previous values of the triggers.
struct WebViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    @Binding var state: WebViewState

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.publisher(for: \.canGoBack).sink {
            state.canGoBack = $0
        }.store(in: &context.coordinator.cancellables)
        webView.publisher(for: \.canGoForward).sink {
            state.canGoForward = $0
        }.store(in: &context.coordinator.cancellables)
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if url != context.coordinator.lastURL {
            context.coordinator.lastURL = url
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(request)
        }
        if context.coordinator.lastGoBackTrigger != state.goBackTrigger {
            context.coordinator.lastGoBackTrigger = state.goBackTrigger
            webView.goBack()
        }
        if context.coordinator.lastGoForwardTrigger != state.goForwardTrigger {
            context.coordinator.lastGoForwardTrigger = state.goForwardTrigger
            webView.goForward()
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        .init()
    }
    
    class Coordinator {
        fileprivate var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
        fileprivate var lastGoBackTrigger = false
        fileprivate var lastGoForwardTrigger  = false
        fileprivate var lastURL: URL? = nil
    }
}

Usage:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var webViewState = WebViewState()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            WebViewWrapper(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!, state: $webViewState)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                        Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                    }
                    if webViewState.canGoBack {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                            Button {
                                webViewState.goBack()
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

It is not suitable to use a ViewModifier here because the ViewModifier cannot be applied to every kind of View. You can encapsulate this more by wrapping it in another View, passing the toolbar builder closure to the initialiser.
struct WebView<ToolBar: ToolbarContent>: View {
    @State var webViewState = WebViewState()
    let url: URL
    let toolbar: ((Binding<WebViewState>) -> ToolBar)?
    
    init(url: URL, @ToolbarContentBuilder toolbar: @escaping (Binding<WebViewState>) -> ToolBar) {
        self.toolbar = toolbar
        self.url = url
    }
    
    // optional toolbar closure
    init(url: URL) where ToolBar == ToolbarItem<(), EmptyView> {
        self.toolbar = nil
        self.url = url
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        WebViewWrapper(url: url, state: $webViewState)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                }
                if let toolbar {
                    toolbar($webViewState)
                }
            }
    }
}

// This way you don't need @State at the use site
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            WebView(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!) { $webViewState in
                if webViewState.canGoBack {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                        Button {
                            webViewState.goBack()
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I'm sorry but I don't understand why the UIViewRepresentable needs to expose the canGoBack and a state struct is needed. Why will my setup to add a closure to the Toolbar ViewModifier not work?

@Pieter What do you mean "why"? As you have identified, you do not have access to a WKWebView in the ViewModifier, because a ViewModifier needs to be applicable to all views. You might be able to pass the WKWebView into the environment, but that is not very idiomatic, and the bigger problem is, the toolbar will not be able to update when WKWebView.canGoBack changes, since SwiftUI does not observe that.

@Pieter You need SwiftUI to observe changes to canGoBack in order for the toolbar to update automatically. SwiftUI can observe changes to a @State, and that is exactly what I have done here. SwiftUI doesn't observe WKWebView.canGoBack, so I manually observed it with KVO, and modifies a @State whenever canGoBack changes. This signals SwiftUI to perform a view update, potentially updating the toolbar, adding/removing the toolbar item.

I had hoped that I could access the WKWebView in the ViewModifier by casting the content body input parameter to WebView for example. From your comments I gather that isn't possible. I'm going to the example in your answer.
